# Align a button (text and icon) with some css

Tags: svg, button, alignment, vertical-alignment, elementor

Good Morning, check please: [example](https://unlatino.com/)
I need to vertically align a button on my website, so that the text and the icon are on the same line. [(see attached photo)](https://ibb.co/pjkCRGD)

I put the class .boton-producto {vertical-align: middle;} but not work.

Maybe a little css can help me.
Thanks.-

Comment: add `align-items: center` to the `.elementor-button-content-wrapper`

Comment: Súper, work my friend! Thanks.